# How to retrieve Firestore data from inside a function?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, string-interpolation

I am trying to call firestore data, the title of a collection, inside a function from a button. It worked when I just used it inside an onPressed:

```
Expanded(
   child: IconButton(
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.share,
         onPressed: () => Share.share(
         '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}',  //this displays the 'title' 
fields of my firestore collections in ListView
         ))),
```

But when trying to call from a function (in a different share plugin), whatever I try just prints the actual code and not the content, how do I retrieve the firestore collection's "title" in the function below, I thought string interpolation ${ like this } was the only way but it doesn't work for this:

```
MaterialButton(
              child: Text('Share text'),
              onPressed: () async => await _shareText(),
            ),
```

function:

```
Future<void> _shareText() async {
try {
  Share.text('my text title',
      'HERE => This is my text to share with other applications.', 'text/plain');  
// no variation of ${snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']} works here
} catch (e) {
  print('error: $e');
}}
```

The string I get the data is:

```
${snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']}
```

Is there another way to call this?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'image.dart';


class Recipe extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_RecipeState createState() => _RecipeState();
}

class _RecipeState extends State<Recipe> {
 var firestoreDb = Firestore.instance.collection("recipes").snapshots();



  // THIS ${(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'])} does not work in 
  share plugin:
Future<void> _shareText() async {
try {
  Share.text('Share Text ',
      '${(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'])}', 'text/plain');
} catch (e) {
  print('error: $e');
}
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Recipes',
                style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                  fontSize: 22.0,
                  color: Colors.amberAccent.shade50,
                ),
              )),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(MdiIcons.foodForkDrink, color: Color(0xffffe0b2), 
size: 32.0),
            onPressed: () {
             null;
            },
          ),
        ]),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
    elevation: 50.0,
  ), //AppBar

  body: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: firestoreDb,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) Text('Loading...');
          return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 6.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, int index) => Container(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                    ),

                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}',
                          style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                            fontSize: 20.0,
                            height: 1.2,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        ),

                        subtitle: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[



                              MaterialButton(
                                child: Text('Share text'),
                                onPressed: () async => await _shareText(),
                              ),

                              SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              ImageInput(),  //this displays image called 
from image_picker to share , it works for sharing an image. 


                              Expanded(
                                child: Text(
                                  '${(snapshot.data.documents[index] 
   ['subtitle'])}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                    fontSize: 13.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  ),
                                ), //subtitle: Text
                              ),
                            ] //children
                        ), //Row
                      ), //listtile
                    ]),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(2),
          );
        }),
  ),
);
} //build
} //class
```

I copied my ImageInput() class page into the main page because I can't get both the image and text to share together, I still see the "undefined" errors for both text and snapshot in the share text field. This same fix doesn't work for the text, although it's on the same page now. What am I doing wrong?

```
MaterialButton(
      child: Text('Send it!'),
      onPressed: () async => await _shareImageAndText(snapshot, index),
    ),

---

Future<void> _shareImageAndText(snapshot, index) async {
try {
  List<int> imageBytes = await _imageFile.readAsBytes();
  var uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
  await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.jpg', uint8List, 'image/jpeg',
      text: (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']) );
      //text: 'My optional text.');
  // (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']), 'text/plain');
  } catch (e) {
  print('error: $e');
  }}
```

---

```
class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {

 File _imageFile;

 void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source){
ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 200.0).then((File image){
  setState((){
    _imageFile = image;
  });
  Navigator.pop(context);

});
 }

  void _openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
 showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 180.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Choose photo',
            style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            child: Text('Use Camera'),
            onPressed: () {
              _getImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
            },),
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,child:
          Text('Open Gallery'),
            onPressed: () {
              _getImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
            },)

        ]
    ),);
});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    OutlineButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _openImagePicker(context);
      },
      child:Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
            SizedBox(
              width:1.0,
            ),
            // Text('Add Image'),
          ]
      ),//Row
    ),//outline button

    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    _imageFile == null ? Text('Add a Pic')  : Image.file(_imageFile,
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      height: 200.0,
      width: 200.0,
      // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    ),

    MaterialButton(
      child: Text('Send it!'),
      onPressed: () async => await _shareImageAndText(),

    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```

Comment: but the code inside the function and the code you used directly is different.Such as Share.share() and Share.text()

Comment: Exactly, I switched from using the Share.share plugin to the Share.text plugin but the firestore database string does not work with the new package. It doesn't display the content, only the code and I can not understand why.

Comment: can you text me the link of your plugin

Comment: @Henok [link](http://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share/blob/master/lib/share.dart)

Comment: the plugin hasn't been updated for 2 years, I recommend changing it to a more active library, and also if you are not getting the title inside the string maybe try to get it right before calling the share and putting it in another variable, String title = snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'], then use the title like 'some string value $title', let me know the results.

Comment: This plugin is the only way I could find that allows an image to be shared along with text, supposedly. I don't understand why there is no other way to share an image file in Flutter.

Comment: Also I tried String title = snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'];
 but I get undefined errors for snapshot and index. Nothing wants to work, even String title =  Firestore.instance.collection("recipes").document('title');

Comment: this shows that the error might not only be from the plugin please post the rest of the code and the error report.

Comment: @Henok full page code above, trying to call _shareText() with firestore string won't work

Comment: thanks for updating your question, don't forget to comment the error when you tried to put in a separate variable, and on first sight '${(snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'])}' is not necessary since it is not concatenated with another string you can just use (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'])

Comment: and also the snapshot exists only inside build how can it be accessed inside the method _shareText(), or is there another snapshot which you haven't posted?

Comment: Undefined name Index, undefined name snapshot in (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']) and in String title = snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'];

Comment: I put (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']) inside shareText() function and I get those 'undefined' errors

Comment: I think i found the issue, try my answer

Comment: I provided wrong link for this share plugin, correct one is [link](https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: ok, have you tried it? let me know I updated the answer also.

Comment: I am running it now it takes a while but I see no errors now, why did the parameters have to be moved, is it a scope issue?

Comment: yes, the snapshot was only inside your build(local) and your shareText doesn't know about them, you have to pass the data to the method in order for it to access.

Comment: still stuck, please see my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Future<void> _shareText(snapshot, index) async {
try {
  Share.text('Share Text ',
      (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']), 'text/plain');
} catch (e) {
  print('error: $e');
}
}
```

and pass the snapshot parameter inside your StreamBuilder call it like this,

`onPressed: () async => await _shareText(snapshot, index),`

Comment: That's another issue, you can post another question for that.

Comment: Had to restart it. I have much still to learn, thank you for your help. Can you point me in the right direction to learn how to call (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']) on another page, for instance my image_picker code is on page ImageInput() class, but I want to add the same text string : (snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title']) on that page also to combine both the image and text share in same function. Is it possible?